# Handling temporaries in stack machine

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, vm-implementation

I have been trying to understand the code generation for a stack machine for MIPS where there is an accumulator register which is used for storing the result of the operation and the 2nd operand to the instruction has to be popped from the stack. 
Most of the lectures and videos seem to talk about instruction sequences like this x + (y + z) and then go on to explain how x will be pushed to stack and then y followed my loading z to accumulator... so on and so forth.

However, am getting a little confused on this scenario.
Let's say no optimizations like constant folding has been done on this following code.

```
A = 2 + 3
X = 1 + 1
....  // More random instructions
B = 4 + 5
C = A + 2
D = B + 1
E = C + D
```

So in this sequence of instructions, the result from each operation is not used in the next instruction. So my guess is that they have to be pushed on to the stack. 
Question is how will they be retrieved? For example A has been calculated. Now is a symbol table maintained for A as to where it's value got pushed onto the stack?
If so, this would work well for an SSA IR but how does it work without SSA in the presence of control flow?
I understand that MIPS has lw & sw instructions which take an offset to load but let's say if the underlying architecture didn't support this kind of instructions. In that case do we pop all the values on top of A whenever we have to retrieve A?

I would appreciate any feedback on how this works and if my question is clear enough.

Comment: If you have a series of stack machine instructions, and you apply constant-folding optimizations, you get a shorter but still valid sequence of stack machine instructions. Common subexpression elimination is another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computation is actually purely functional (variables are assigned only once), then you can always arrange the computation as an expression tree (in which the variable assignments are gone) and evaluate it in the obvious way with a stack machine and nothing else.  You still need an instruction to push the value of an already-initialized variable on the stack, that is, something that can refer to an area outside the stack.

That's nice but not realistic. Most languages have assignments used for side effects, to remember state; the compiler may detect that you have a common subexpression, compute the result, store into a temporory for later use, etc.   Clearly the target memory locations for such assignments cannot be in the stack without making the simple stack machine evaluation process more complicated somehow, and that avoids its prettiness and probably damages performance.  (If we were seriously after performance, we'd be using a register machine).

Ultimately variables requiring "long-term storage" (relative to the duration of the evaluation of some subsequence of stack machine instructions) need to be stored in a memory "outside" the stack.  The compiler can assign each variable name a unique location in that outside area; with care, it can allocate such locations in a way that variables that are not "live" at the same time can use the same memory locations, minimizing the size of that outside area.   You already had need for an instruction to load values from outside the stack ("push "); any realistic architecture will correspondingly have instructions to store the top value into that area ("pop ").

Some stack machine architectures allow pushing of any operand already in the stack; easily generalized to storing into any operand (slot) already in the stack.  This is just a hybrid combining "inside the stack" and "outside the stack"; you can always dedicate the far-away "bottom" of the stack as an area you will only use in a non-stack like way.   But this is just simulating "outside the stack".

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ira. So essentially what I am getting from your answer is this. The stack is essentially used for recursively evaluating expressions. So any variable which is not used in subsequent instructions but has a liveness will be stored into memory. Efficiently managing the memory is the compiler's job which is essentially then very similar to the register allocator problem since in both case you are trying to minimize the number of registers/memory locations used based on the liveness analysis. The "long term storage" could either be physical memory or stack reserved space.

Comment: That's pretty much right.  As a practical matter, good compilers don't typically generate stack machine code; they manage the registers well enough.   You only tend to see pushes for arguments to a function that takes many arguments.